# How to generate pre-signed url to connect with websocket in aws chime?

Tags: python, android, node.js, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I am creating a mobile application in which I need to implement chat feature. Now, How can I connect with aws chime using websocket pre-signed url from the mobile app so that I don';t need to store credentials in mobile app ? I want to provide this pre-signed url to mobile frontend via api. I have seen one example in python and also I have converted it in javascript. but I don't have sessionId. so how to get that sessionId also ?

I have gone throught this python [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67340546/how-to-create-aws-chime-presigned-url-to-generate-web-socket-url-for-the-front-e). I converted it into javascript. But I don't have sessionId.